# How can I specify which components of an extension to use

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have two extensions installed that provide some overlapping features. Specifically, both extensions provide language grammars.

One extension has a comprehensive language server, that provides intelligent snippets and such, but has an inferior colorizer. Another language provides a much better colorizer, but has no auxiliary features (i.e. no language server).

**I would like to ensure that the superior colorizer is always chosen over the inferior one, while retaining both extensions features. So far, I cannot find any way of explicitly doing this.**